# Basic MSI Project - XML or Binary?

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

Installshield allows to 2 types of project file types - **XML & Binary**, in a Basic MSI project.

What should discourage me from using XML project file type over Binary type?

I have 2 of those listed listed below, but are these correct?

- Slowing opening and closing time on big project files
- May slow down InstallShield compile/build process

Answer (score 1):

build time is not affected.
Loading time is also not that different, I just checked with one of my projects who has about 6,000 files in it, and the time to open it seems almost identical (maybe 1-2 seconds slower on the XML project)

Answer (score 1):

There are two potentially significant differences, depending on how you use your projects:

- As a poorly-kept-secret, the Binary format is compatible with Windows Installer automation and editing tools, but the XML format is generally not.
- However the XML format is more amenable to text-based viewing, editing, source control, or XML-based automation.

There are several additional differences I know about that I consider insigificant:

- The representations differ, so you will see size differences in the resulting project files.
- It is a conversion, as InstallShield works internally with the Binary format, so it takes some (minimal) extra time to load and save the project file.
- The code that converts internally between XML and Binary representation is well-used, but it's still a conversion. That's additional complexity, so loading and saving as XML has more points of potential failure.
- There are some slight behavioral differences after deleting a record "in the middle." Saving and loading through XML will normalize this and add a new record at the end; working in Binary may reuse the deleted record's spot for the next record. However record order is not semantically significant.